# Digits of number and output

Tags: c

I have a problem that this code doesn't end with output.

I appreciate if help me.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int number,counter=0;
    scanf("%d",&number);
    while (number!=0){
        number=number/10;
        counter++;
    }
    printf("the number has %d digits",&counter);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should remove "&" from your printf statement.

& is for scanning not printing

the correct form is :

```
printf("the number has %d digits",counter);
```

Comment: Thank you . It worked properly.

Comment: @EricAnderson If this answer helped you, please upvote and accept it (by clicking on the checkmark).

Comment: "& is for scanning not printing" The reason is a little bit more complicated.

Comment: @justANewbie True, but for people who are just starting out, who are using `printf` and `scanf` but are still months away from learning about pointers, learning "use `&` for `scanf` but not for `printf`" really does just about cover it.  (Also the exception: "Except don't use `&` with `%s`".)